# Default instance(maybe static) of Messenger plugin like MVVM Light

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Is there an equivalent in MVVMCross to MVVM Light's `Messenger.Default` instance(for standalone projects that don't comply with MVVM in Xamarin.iOS).

After looking at threads such as [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8638/mvvmlight-with-mvvmcross), [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger), [this](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n9-getting-message-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html)

I decided to add the "MvvmCross Messenger" plugin to the PCL and iOS project. Thought I'd have to register the Hub and resolve it from the PCL and iOS projects with something like

```cs
// Registering in ViewDidLoad() of iOS project
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMessenger>(new MvxMessengerHub());

// Try to resolve and subscribe in PCL and iOS project - both have nuget packages added
_messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger> ();
_token = _messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<MyMessage> ((message) => {
    OutputLabel.Text = message.Number;
});
```

However I get a null reference exception right at `Mvx.RegisterSingleton`. Not too sure what I'm missing. All I'm looking for is the Messenger to function. Do not want any other part of MVVM in this project *for now*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MvvmCross we made our messenger optional - so it's in a plugin.

If you want to use it standalone, then you can boot the plugin system using code like that shown in the CrossLight demos - see N=30 and N=39 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/ - and see the android-only demos in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/CrossLight/PluginUse/NoBinding/Setup.cs

For iOS, you'll probably need some one-time init code something like:

```
        if (MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance != null)
            return;

        var ioc = MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize();

        ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new MvxDebugOnlyTrace());
        var manager = new MvxLoaderPluginManager();
        var registry = new MvxLoaderPluginRegistry(".Touch", manager);                          
        ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxPluginManager>(manager);
```

The code for the messenger itself is in: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/Messenger/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs

Alternatively... if you don't want Mvx code for binding, dispatcher, etc, then it's probably easier to just use something like the excellent TinyMessenger - https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger

Comment: Cheers for your reply. I guess I'll have a look at TinyMessenger then for now with the project not using MVVM. Would love to just use MVVMCross on the iOS project but with Storyboards, it is still a lil bit awkward mixing VM's and segue's.